# Switching between workspaces doesn't work - how to fix it?

Tags: 11.10, workspaces

I've updated to Ubuntu Oneiric and my workspaces are gone. Better put, keyboard shortcuts CTRL + ALT + LEFT/RIGHT arrow do not work now.

Is it possible that compiz is broken somehow? Can I repair it?

**Note:** I've used developer versions of Ubuntu Oneiric some time and just upgrade to latest version now.

Thanks for a suggestion!

Comment: You can see your desktops using **Super+s** right?

Comment: Yes. But remaining workspaces are empty and I cannot move an app there.

Answer (score 5):

Check using `CompizConfig Settings Manager` (install if you dont have it) the number of virtual desktops assigned (horizontal and vertical size):

[image]

Then have a look at `System Settings`>`Keyboard`>`Shortcuts`>`Navigation` and check your assigned keyboard shortcuts there:

[image]

Try assigning new keys for them, if that works try reverting the original keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I don't have options like: "switch to workspace X" (neither do I have "move to workspace left/right/...") in my dialog.

Comment: Have a look at the edit: use ccsm to check the number of desktops you have.

Comment: If I set `horizontal virtual size` and `vertical virtual size` to 1 my ctrl+alt+<left/right> dont work even tough I can see 4 desktops using **super+s**.

Comment: I had number of desktops one. I changed it to 4 and nothing really changed :(

Comment: horizontal virtual size and vertical virtual size were set on 2?

Comment: this doesnt seem to be doing anything atm in my vbox 11.10 (tested on 11.04). Ill try to have a look at it further and edit answer. sec

Comment: bruno: yes, both are set to 2.

Comment: im really lost, a reinstall of ubuntu-desktop is out of the question?

Comment: http://gourgi.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/re-install-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage-and-reinstall-its-dependencies/ -- I tried this but it has not helped.

Comment: To remove a package and configs you do `apt-get clean <nameof package>` place it on that command (as this): `sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | \
sed '/^$/d' | xargs sudo apt-get \
clean --yes` to completely remove that packages + config files! (DO A BACKUP OF ALL THAT IS IMPORTANT IN THIS LIFE THAT YOU KEEP ON THIS COMPUTER BEFORE RUNNING THIS!!!)

Comment: after you can install all again with `sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | \
sed '/^$/d' | xargs sudo apt-get \
install --install-recommends --yes`

Comment: Really hope this does its thing, if you don't find an answer the only other path is clean install :S Hope for the best, gl!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use gconf-editor and put Expo as the last plugin to load. I use hot corners though.

To do this you will have to install gconf-edtor, run it, then select 'apps' > compiz-1 > general > screen0 > options and double click on 'active_plugins'.

Comment: I did that. Am I supposed to restart Ubuntu? Or somehow apply changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: That is indeed odd. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: Does the graphics card matter? It worked in Natty just fine.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters or not... but it might.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with non-standard shortcuts used -- icould only change left and down...

I solved it by going to to keyboard shortcuts (Now keyboard > shortcuts) and changing the shortcuts to something used for something else, and then back (a couple of times, sort of "jiggling it").

Try for example changing the  "workspace left" to shortcut to Ctrl+Alt+Up and "workspace right" to Ctrl+Alt+Down, and then set all four again afterwards.

I have no idea why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gnome tweaks, try disabling extensions to see if any is catching the keyboard shortcuts. For me, `workspace switchER wraparound` was the problem, while `workspace switch wraparound` worked for me. For others, the reverse might be true. First step is identifying the culprit though.

(ubuntu 18.10 cosmic)